# Laravel 5.2 Access control list

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, entrust

I am new to Laravel, and feeling very uncomfortable about embedding the "Entrust" plugin in Laravel 5.2.
Can any one please tell me how I can embed "Entrust" in Laravel 5.2?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the package on [Link](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) then you have all the neccessary documentation there

Comment: no i am referring to the package on windows like 10 . . .i have found many tutorials out there on web but that are mostly for 4.2 or 5

Comment: I want for laravel 5.2 please it's a humble request to all that assist me to embed entrust for ACL in laravel 5.2